Estimate the Power Spectral Dentity of a signal from CWT coefficients
I want to estimate the PSD of a signal from the CWT coefficients. How can I do it? Can you provide me with some algorithms to do this? I have Matlab R$2016$a installed. Thank you so much! I do this code but the PSD estimate isn`t similar to the original one:
% Constants and Signal Definition
Fs = 1000; % Sampling frequency in Hz
duracion = 1; % Duration in seconds
N = Fs * duracion; % Total number of samples
delta = zeros(1, N); % Initialize delta function
delta(round(N/2)) = sqrt(N); % Impulse in the center
scales=1:16;
cwtCoeffs = cwt(delta, scales, 'db6'); % CWT
% Compute the absolute square of the CWT coefficients
cwtCoeffsSquared = abs(cwtCoeffs).^2;
% Compute the time-averaged power, which gives the scalogram
scalogram = mean(cwtCoeffsSquared, 2);
% Normalize the scalogram to get the relative energy distribution as a function of frequency, which is the PSD
psd = scalogram / sum(scalogram);
% Plot the PSD
frequencies = Fs * (0:(length(psd)/2))/length(psd);
plot(frequencies, 10*log10((psd(1:length(frequencies)))));
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Power Spectral Density (dB/Hz)');
% FFT-based PSD
X = fft(delta); 
Pxx1_delta = 2*abs(X(1:N/2)).^2/(N*Fs); % PSD computation
frecuencias = linspace(0, Fs/2, N/2); % Frequency vector for FFT
hold on
plot(frecuencias, 10*log10(Pxx1_delta))

